# Mobile Browser TouchEvents

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

Is there a way to get touch events to be relative to the element and not the view port or the entire page?

I have the code,

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = 100;
c.height = 100;
c.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
    de.innerHTML = e.targetTouches[0].clientX + ", " + e.targetTouches[0].clientY;
}, false);
```

de being just a div to output data to, but clientX and clientY are not relative to the element. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be relative to the element, you can be relative to:

- The **Viewport** (clientX,clientY as you used).
- The **screen**, it handles zooming (screenX...)
- The **page**, it handles scrolling (pageX...)

For further info read the useful [mobile safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1) reference guide, and/or [Sitepen's article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/comment-page-1/) on this topic.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I had already found those pages. I Think i've come up with a solution for calculating the values based on the elements position on the page.